# Output method in an HTML block

Tags: php, html, function, fwrite

I have a method that keeps different function that output a html-snippet.

```
function col2_article() {
  CA_2Col::createOuter2Table();
    CA_2Col::createInner2Table();
      CA_2Col::createInnerMso2Table();
        CA_2Col::createContentLeftTable();
          CA_2Col::col2_content();
        CA_2Col::closeContentLeftTable();
      CA_2Col::createMiddleMso2Table();
        CA_2Col::createContentRightTable();
          CA_2Col::col2_content();
        CA_2Col::closeContentRightTable();
      CA_2Col::closeMso2Table();
    CA_2Col::close2Table();
  CA_2Col::close2Table();
}
```

Is it possible to output this function in a HTML file?

I tried it with fwrite statement but the content was only output in the page and not insert in the HTML file.

```
function createHTML() {
    $ca = $this->col2_article();
    $ca_name = 'Test';
    $myfile = fopen("files/". $ca_name .".html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $ca);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: instead of `.html` use `.php` so that it can work on browser

Comment: I see the output in my browser but my "Test.html" file which i wanna create is empty, also when i try to save into a Test.php file

Comment: what is there in `$ca`? can you show `var_dump($ca)?`

Comment: in var_dump($ca) i get NULL.. if i call my method i get the html block.. but i dont know how to store this information in my file creator. the functions which i call in this function all has an echo and no return

Comment: if `var_dump($ca)==NULL` that means either  `$this->col2_article();` is not calling the function or have some issue. As you are saying that `if i call my method i get the html block`. I am not sure that how's you ar calling so that somewhere it worked and with `$this->col2_article()` not working

Comment: if i call $this->col2_article() in my view, the html block appears.. when i store it first in a variable i get NULL.. and fwirte($myfile, $this->col2_article()); not work.. so my question is how can i call the function mybe there is another work around? but i have unfortunately, no idea

Comment: The solution was quite easy! I stored my result of the function in an echo or a return statement.. i change it to an variable that i return and it works like a charme!

Comment: Since this is solved, would you write an answer in the answer box below, weristsam? That will give you the ability to self-accept it too, via the tick icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite easy! First, I stored my result of the function in an `echo` or a `return` statement.. Now, I save the result of every function into an variable that I return, and it works like a charm!